# SSH dont pick up changes in config file (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I made a simple change to the SSHd config, but it never get picked up by the SSH Daemon.

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

no error is reported, any idea what it may be, or where i can look?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the init script.

you can use

```
service ssh restart
```

and the config change is picked up as it should.